# Aliasing ExampleGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In RSpec I can give alias to examples. For instance, `alias_example_to`.
Is there any way of aliasing Example Groups? I can use only `describe` and `context`. But I want to use, say, `feature`, `scenario`...etc. For example,

```
describe MyObject do
  scenario "doing smth with object" do
  ...
  end
end
```

I found an article on http://benediktdeicke.com/2013/01/custom-rspec-example-groups/.
Is there any other way to alias Example Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround until the feature is released is this:

```
# spec/support/example_group_aliases.rb
module ExampleGroupAliases
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class << self
      alias_method :simple, :context
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def fancy(description, options = {}, &block)
      context(description, options.merge(:fancy => true), &block)
    end
  end

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include self
  end
end
```

The code shows two ways of defining aliases for the `context` method. The first (`simple`) one is using `alias_method`. The second one (`fancy`) is defining a new method that then calls the original `context` method. The last approach allows you to do additional stuff, like adding some more options.

Comment: it does not work. Perhaps because my project is not Rails one, it is a pure Ruby project. I am writing a gem. Any suggestions?

Comment: got it!!, it worked. simply add => require 'active_support/concern'  in spec/support/example_group_aliases.rb. Now, I can write more readable specs. Unfortunately I cannot vote up your answer since I have less than 15 reputations. Anyway, thanks both to Peter Alfvin and Benedikt Deicke.

Comment: Could you give an example where I could use the second one (fancy)? I cannot imagine what I could use it for.

Comment: You could filter what examples to run by defining a tag: `rspec -t fancy spec/` would only run those specs defined within `fancy` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

As I interpret github, this feature was requested via https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/493 and is awaiting integration via https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/870.  It is not yet available.

Comment: thank you for reply. Let's wait until it is available. Until then I'll have to do with describe and context. :-)